# How do I read two dot operators in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm currently reading on doubly linked lists, but I don't seem to understand this line of code. The book calls it a two dot operator and says it's a natural extension of a single dot operator but I'm not too sure what that explicitly means.

```
newLink.next = current.next; 
current.next.previous = newLink;
```

What exactly is .next.previous pointing to here?

Comment: They just made up a name, maybe for didactic reasons. But there is nothing special in the second dot. So current.next is the field "next in "current" and now current.next.previous  is the field "previous" in the field "current .next"

Comment: Are there other next/previous modifications to current and newLink? This code seems incomplete.

Comment: Are there also lines like `current.next = newlink;` and `newlink.previous = current;`? What you have looks like part of a node insertion.

Comment: You can chain as many dot operators as you want. For example, human.leftArm.hand.ringFinger.fingernail would be fetching the fingernail of the left hand's ring finger, so naming it a two dot operator is disingenuous.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are accessing a visible property of a defined type. See this code for an example:

```
Node current = null ; // defined to working node, null on new list 
Node head = null ; // defined during list creation
Node tail = null ; // defined during list extension
Node newLink = new Node () ; // for example -- in practice this would 
                             // be created on insert

public Node { 
    Node next = null ; 
    Node previous = null ; 
    Object data = null ; 
} 

// some ops here to traverse, insert, replace (and always null or end check)
```

You are not using getters and setters. The "two dot operator" is simply accessing defined properties of each Node. So when you say, current.next.previous you are getting the properties from inside those particular Nodes directly.

**More detail:** From current's next (the Node named 'next' in the Node named current), you then get previous (the Node named 'previous' from the Node named 'next' in the Node named 'current').

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way:

```
Link t = current.next; //gives you another link which is next for the current link
t.previous = newLink;
```

It just accesses the "previous" of the "next" link, it's just written inline.
In this specific example, it points to a reference (of itself) in it's "next" link and replaces it with newLink. This code seems to replace `current` with `newLink`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Doubly Linked List, next points to the next Node in the List and gives you next Node. Now for convenience you can replace `current.next` with a variable like nextNode so it becomes nextNode.previous which is much simpler to understand that it is pointing to the previous element of nextNode which is current Node itself.